# Bash string variable declaration

Tags: bash, variables

What's the difference between `name="${name:-Henry}"` and `name="Henry"` in bash?

Comment: If the variable is not set, use the default (`"Henry"` in this case)

Comment: Read: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: Thanks and sorry for asking the question without proper research